# JavaScript - Insert HTML markup into string given styling indexes

Tags: javascript, html

I have a piece of text.

```
"This is a test to see whether nested style spans work properly."
```

I have the styling information as a JSON object, e.g.

```
0: {start: 22, end: 54, type: "strong"}
1: {start: 30, end: 36, type: "hyperlink", data: {…}}
2: {start: 37, end: 48, type: "em"}
3: {start: 43, end: 48, type: "hyperlink", data: {…}}
```

The text is supposed to look like

```html
<p>This is a test to see <strong>whether <a href="https://www.google.co.za">nested</a> <em>style <a href="https://www.google.co.za">spans</a></em> work </strong>properly.</p>
```

What should be the general approach for an algorithm? The problem is that the indexes contained in the styling information obviously become obsolete once I start inserting markup into the text to style it.

I tried keeping track of the length of characters I'm inserting through a buffer (so that the indexes could be adjusted with the buffer length), but that became an issue with nested tags. My entire 'solution' feels incredibly clumsy and unwieldy, I'm sure there must be a better approach.

This is the code I've attempted.

```
NewsUtils.styleSpanCSS = span => {
let styledSpan = {};
  switch (span.type) {
    case "em":
      styledSpan.opening = "<span";
      styledSpan.style = ' class="italic">';
      styledSpan.closing = "</span>";
      break;
    case "hyperlink":
      styledSpan.opening = `<a href="${span.data.url}">`;
      styledSpan.style = "";
      styledSpan.closing = "</a>";
      break;
    case "strong":
      styledSpan.opening = "<span";
      styledSpan.style = ' class="bold">';
      styledSpan.closing = "</span>";
      break;
    default:
      styledSpan.opening = "";
      styledSpan.style = "";
      styledSpan.closing = "";
  }
  styledSpan.length =
    styledSpan.opening.length +
    styledSpan.style.length +
    styledSpan.closing.length;
  return styledSpan;
};

NewsUtils.styleParagraph = elem => {

  if (elem.spans.length > 0) {
    let buffer = 0;
    elem.spans.map(span => {
      let elementToInsert = NewsUtils.styleSpanCSS(span);
      let spanLength =
        elementToInsert.opening.length +
        elementToInsert.style.length +
        elementToInsert.closing.length;
      elem.text =
        elem.text.substring(0, span.start + buffer) +
        elementToInsert.opening +
        elementToInsert.style +
        elem.text.substring(span.start + buffer, span.end + buffer) +
        elementToInsert.closing +
        elem.text.substring(span.end + buffer, elem.text.length + buffer);
      buffer += spanLength;);
    });
    return <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: elem.text }} />;
  }
  return <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: elem.text }} />;
};

NewsUtils.markupParagraphs = post => {
  const postDetails = post.data.text.map(elem => {
  switch (elem.type) {
    case "paragraph":
      return NewsUtils.styleParagraph(elem);
    case "image":
      return (
        <img
          src={elem.url}
          width={elem.dimensions.width}
          height={elem.dimensions.height}
        />
      );
    case "embed":
      let url = elem.oembed.embed_url;
      url = url.substring(0, url.indexOf("&"));
      url = url.replace("watch?v=", "embed/");
      url = url.replace("vimeo.com", "player.vimeo.com/video");
      return <iframe src={url} frameBorder="0" allowFullScreen />;
    default:
      return null;
  }
  });
  return postDetails;
};
};
```

Comment: Where is the `javascript` where you attempt to use the `JSON` to make changes to the string? Please include your attempt. Stackoverflow is not here to write things for you.

Comment: @NewToJS Thanks for the comment, I've added the code. I don't want to go into specifics of what I've done though, that doesn't seem like pertinent information. I rather want to understand what the correct approach is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a basic implementation. I got rid of the hyperlink special handling to demonstrate the algorithm itself, but it should be easy to add that logic back in:

```js
const text = 'This is a test to see whether nested style spans work properly.'
const styling = [
  {start: 22, end: 54, type: "strong"},
  {start: 30, end: 36, type: "a"},
  {start: 37, end: 48, type: "em"},
  {start: 43, end: 48, type: "a"}
];

const result = [...text].reduce((a, v, i) => {
  styling.filter(s => s.start === i).forEach(s => a += `<${s.type}>`);
  styling.filter(s => s.end === i).forEach(s => a += `</${s.type}>`);
  return a + v;
}, '');

document.body.innerHTML = result;
```

Output:

```html
This is a test to see <strong>whether <a>nested</a> <em>style <a>spans</em></a> work </strong>properly.
```

If your input and styling array are large, you might want to create temporary lookup objects to increase performance.

Comment: @NickParsons Done. The hyperlinks are not correctly displayed due to the lack of an `href` attribute, but I want to keep the focus on the algorithm in my answer.

Comment: Wow, very nice! Thank you, sir.

Answer (score 2):

Splitting into array of characters allows for insertions at specific index without affecting the rest of the indexes :

```js
const text = 'This is a test to see whether nested style spans work properly.'
const json = `{ "0": {"start": 22, "end": 54, "type": "strong"},
                "1": {"start": 30, "end": 36, "type": "hyperlink"},
                "2": {"start": 37, "end": 48, "type": "em"},
                "3": {"start": 43, "end": 48, "type": "hyperlink"} }`

const letters = text.split('')
JSON.parse(json, (k, v) => v.type ? 
  (letters[v.start] = '<' + v.type + '>' + letters[v.start], 
   letters[v.end]  = '</' + v.type + '>' + letters[v.end]   ) : v)

console.log( letters.join('') )
console.log( letters )
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert string to array contain letters using `.split()` and loop through result array. In loop find object that index of letter is equal to `start` or `end` of it.

```
var newStr = "";
// Loop through letters
str.split('').forEach(function(letter, i){
  // Loop through object
  for (key in obj){
    // If letter index is equal to key start
    if (obj[key].start == i)
      newStr += obj[key].type == "hyperlink" ? 
        '<a href="https://www.google.co.za">' : 
        '<'+obj[key].type+'>';
    // If letter index is equal to key end
    if (obj[key].end == i)
      newStr += obj[key].type == "hyperlink" ? 
        '</a>' : 
        '</'+obj[key].type+'>';
  }
  newStr += letter;
});
// Wrap result in <p></p>
newStr = "<p>"+newStr+"</p>";
document.write(newStr);
```

```js
var str = "This is a test to see whether nested style spans work properly.";
var obj = {
  0: {start: 22, end: 54, type: "strong"},
  1: {start: 30, end: 36, type: "hyperlink", data: {}},
  2: {start: 37, end: 48, type: "em"},
  3: {start: 43, end: 48, type: "hyperlink", data: {}}
};

var newStr = "";
str.split('').forEach(function(letter, i){
  for (key in obj){
    if (obj[key].start == i)
      newStr += obj[key].type == "hyperlink" ? 
        '<a href="https://www.google.co.za">' : 
        '<'+obj[key].type+'>';
    if (obj[key].end == i)
      newStr += obj[key].type == "hyperlink" ? 
        '</a>' : 
        '</'+obj[key].type+'>';
  }
  newStr += letter;
});
newStr = "<p>"+newStr+"</p>";
```

Comment: "You need to convert string to array contain letters using .split() and loop through result array." I don't understand how that would solve the problem of the styling indexes becoming unusable after I've started to insert markup since they're no longer accurate? It can be done they way I've thought about it, but I refuse to believe it's the best way.

Answer (score 0):

This approach sorts the given positions to the most inner range first and then takes the outer style.

```js
var string = 'This is a test to see whether nested style spans work properly.',
    makeup = [{ start: 0, end: 63, type: "p" }, { start: 22, end: 54, type: "strong" }, { start: 30, end: 36, type: "hyperlink", data: { link: 'http://example.com/#1' } }, { start: 37, end: 48, type: "em" }, { start: 43, end: 48, type: "hyperlink", data: { link: 'http://example.com/#2' } }],
    sorted = [],
    positions = Array.from(string),
    i, j,
    result;

while (makeup.length > 1) {
    i = 0;
    j = 1;
    while (j < makeup.length) {
        if (makeup[j].start >= makeup[i].start && makeup[j].end <= makeup[i].end) {
            i = j;
        }
        j++;
    }
    sorted.push(makeup.splice(i, 1)[0]);
}
sorted.push(makeup.splice(0, 1)[0]);

sorted.forEach(({ start, end, type, data }) => {
    var [header, footer] = type === 'hyperlink'
        ? [`<a href="${ data.link }">`, '</a>']
        : [`<${ type }>`, `</${ type }>`];

    positions[start] = header + positions[start];
    positions[end - 1] += footer;
});

result = positions.join('');
console.log(result);
document.body.innerHTML += result;
```